# How to check two argument in java is either one of them null or both

Tags: java, string

I want to validate below condition but something is going wrong with my if condition and returning invalid results. **My validations are:**
Either `productId` or `productAltID` can have value or both can be `null`
If both `productId` and `productAltID` are null, then `productSellDate` and `productReturnDate` must have value.

If `productSellDate` and `productReturnDate` are `null`, then `productId` or `productAltID` should have value.

Please find my code below, I'm getting incorrect result not sure what I'm messing up here:

```
public class validate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String productId = null;
        String productAltID = "adfafadsf";
        Date productSellDate = null;
        Date productReturnDate = new Date();

        if (productId != null || productAltID != null || productSellDate !=null && productReturnDate != null) {
            System.out.println("validation success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("validation failed");
        }

    }
}
```

**// Valid Scenarios**

```
Combination 1: Valid Scenario
        String productId = null;
        String productAltID = null;
        Date productSellDate = new Date();
        Date productReturnDate = new Date();


Combination 2: Valid Scenario
        String productId = null;
        String productAltID = "3432fefsf";
        Date productSellDate = new Date();
        Date productReturnDate = new Date();

Combination 3: Valid Scenario
        String productId = "sdf3234234324";
        String productAltID = "3432fefsf";
        Date productSellDate = null;
        Date productReturnDate = null;

Combination 4: Valid Scenario
        String productId = null;
        String productAltID = "3432fefsf";
        Date productSellDate = null;
        Date productReturnDate = null;
```

Comment: logical `&&` is evaulated before `||`.  Try adding parentheses in your if condition.  Or better yet, create methods that you described in the question  for the various conditions so that: `if (isSomeCondition(...) || isSomeOtherCondition(...) || isYetSomeOtherCondition(...))`.

Comment: I think you basically need and `else if` component or try using something like `if ((productId != null || productAltID != null) || (productSellDate != null && productReturnDate != null)) {`

Comment: @DaveBrady, can you provide an example where the actual result differs from the expected value?  Existing code seems to be fine.

Comment: Your Question could be improved by showing some invalid data examples. Also, your prose describing the business rules could be written more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

The [Answer by drekbour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69831543/642706) is correct, operator precedence rules and the lack of parentheses mean your `||` and `&&` operators execute in an order different than you intend.

Here is an alternative approach using `Objects.nonNull` and streams to execute the logic you want, in a readable format.

```java
Stream
.of( productId , productAltID )
.anyMatch( Objects :: nonNull )              // One or more ID fields have a value.
||                                           // … or …
Stream
.of( productSellDate , productReturnDate )
.allMatch( Objects :: nonNull )              // All dates have a value.
```

## Details

### `Objects.nonNull`

Modifying the [code by drekbour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69831543/642706), I would suggest using [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) & [`Objects.isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object)) for easier reading.

Also, I would use more descriptive variable naming.

```java
boolean atLeastOneIdHasValue = Objects.nonNull( productId ) || Objects.nonNull( productAltID ) ;  // One or both ID fields have a value.
boolean bothDatesHaveValue = Objects.nonNull( productSellDate ) && Objects.nonNull( productReturnDate ) ;  // Both dates have a value.
boolean valid = ( atLeastOneIdHasValue || bothDatesHaveValue ) ;
```

### Streams

Another approach uses [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Make a stream of your variables:

```
Stream.of( productId , productAltID )
```

Then tally if any or all match our criterion.

- Call [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) to see whether *any elements* of this stream match the provided predicate.
- Call [`Stream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) to see whether *all elements* of this stream match the provided predicate.

In our case, the predicate is simply a call to [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)).

```java
boolean atLeastOneIdHasValue = Stream.of( productId , productAltID ).anyMatch( x -> Objects.nonNull( x ) ) ;  // One or more ID fields have a value.
boolean bothDatesHaveValue = Stream.of( productSellDate , productReturnDate ).allMatch( x -> Objects.nonNull( x ) ) ;  // All dates have a value.
boolean valid = ( atLeastOneIdHasValue || bothDatesHaveValue ) ;
```

We can shorten that code by using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as our predicate: `Objects :: nonNull`.

```java
boolean atLeastOneIdHasValue = Stream.of( productId , productAltID ).anyMatch( Objects :: nonNull ) ;  // One or more ID fields have a value.
boolean bothDatesHaveValue = Stream.of( productSellDate , productReturnDate ).allMatch( Objects :: nonNull ) ;  // All dates have a value.
boolean valid = ( atLeastOneIdHasValue || bothDatesHaveValue ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rFJtGb).

---

## Avoid `Date` class

By the way, never use `Date` class, nor `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Timestamp`, etc. Those are now legacy, part of the terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

- For a date only (year-month-day), use `LocalDate`.
- For a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds), use `Instant`.
- For a moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: This could be part of a good book!

Answer (score 5):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831227/how-to-check-two-argument-in-java-is-either-one-of-them-null-or-both#comment123437427_69831227), the operator `&&` binds tighter than `||` so the logic wasn't doing what you wished it was. See [*Operators*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) page of the Oracle tutorial.

A little [Literate Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) goes a long way to avoiding this sort of thing.

```java
boolean hasAnId = productId != null || productAltID != null;
boolean hasDates = productSellDate != null && productReturnDate != null;
if ( hasAnId || hasDates ) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's put it like this:

```java
public static boolean isValid(
    String productId, String productAltId, Date sellDate, Date returnDate
) {
    if (null == productId && null == productAltId) {
        return null != sellDate && null != returnDate; // dates MUST have value
    }
    // here productId or productAltId have value, no need to check dates
    return true;
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(isValid(null, null, new Date(), new Date())); // true
System.out.println(isValid(null, "ab", new Date(), new Date())); // true
System.out.println(isValid("cd", "ab", null, null));             // true
System.out.println(isValid("cd", null, null, null));             // true
```